# How do I detect clicking and double-clicking a node in a TreeView?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How do I track the event of clicking a node or double-clicking a node item (meaning, that textual thing next to the plus sign) in a tree view, but not the treeview itself?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.OnChange

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/VCL.ResXplorer_Sample

http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/controls/tcontrol.onmousedown.html

http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/comctrls/tcustomtreeview.onselectionchanged.html

But better use VirtualTreeView

Comment: There's no such thing as OnSelectionChanged in Delphi 7.

Answer (score 4):

Detect a click or double-click on the control in general with the `OnClick` and `OnDblClick` events. To find out which specific node was clicked, use the control's [`GetNodeAt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.GetNodeAt) method with the mouse's current coordinates.

You can get the coordinates as they were at the time of the click with [`GetMessagePos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644938.aspx); reading `Mouse.CursorPos` will give you the coordinates at the time you read the property, which might be very different from the time of the click if there is any sort of load on the system, and that can lead to detecting clicks at places that aren't even within the bounds of your control.

Comment: Could you give a real example. I don't even know how to figure out what coordinates a node has when I'm clicking it.

Comment: You don't have to figure out the coordinates of the node. Like I said, call GetMessagePos to discover the coordinates of your click, and then call GetNodeAt to find out which node (if any) is at that position.

Comment: I found that the upper / lower words of GetMessagePos were the screen positions of the cursor and had to use TTreeControl.ScreenToClient to convert this to coordinates relative to the TTreeView control which could then be fed into TTreeControl.GetNodeAt(...)

Answer (score 0):

Use usual `OnClick` and `OnDblClick` events and look which is the current node item.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTreeView.Selected

See also linked examples.

---

But better use VirtualTreeView.

- http://www.lischke-online.de/VirtualTreeview/VTGallery.php
- http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/

Comment: Your answer is identical to mine. So, fine I delete mine and you can have it. But -1 for the off topic suggestion to use a totally different component.

Comment: Who was posting 1st is not that much different, so your deletion was not necessary. However after answering the question (which i did) i can add any additional suggestion.

Comment: I don't see the point of having multiple identical answers. I'm happy to remove mine so that the question is not cluttered. But proposing a completely different component is radical. Perhaps as a comment, but it serves no purpose in the answer.

Comment: When there is more room in the tree view than it is needed for the tree items, you would be able to click on the "white" area and that wouldn't change the current selection. Responding to that click with an `OnClick` handler would essentially be handling a click on the tree view itself which is precisely what the OP doesn't want.

Comment: The `GetHitTestInfoAt`method gives you all the information you want.